# Error in sql_server package from community opscode

Tags: ruby, windows, chef-infra

I am tring to install sql server in windows using chef

i found this [sql_server](http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/sql_server)

im getting an error

```
uninitialized constant Chef::Win32::Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
```

Comment: What version of Chef? What version of the cookbook?

Comment: @sethvargo Chef version 11.6.2 and windows cookbook version is 1.2.6 and sql cookbook version 1.3.1

Answer (score 1):

If you are running an older version of Chef client that does not have this constant defined, you will get this error.

See: http://lists.opscode.com/sympa/arc/chef/2014-01/msg00073.html

Comment: @sethvargo i have updated to 11.8.2 now i am getting other error:: Chef::Exceptions::Win32RegNoRecursive: registry_key[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib\Tcp\IPAll] (sql_server::server line 56) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::Win32RegNoRecursive: Intermediate keys missing but recursive is set to false

Comment: @sethvargo and Julian, I am running Chef 11.10.0 on Windows 2008 R2 and I'm getting this same error on a clean node with just sql_server::server in the run list. I read at that link that 11.8 is fine, but is it possible this error has returned in 11.10?

Answer (score 0):

For me it helped to add `::` in front of the constant to break out of any namespace, so it would look like this

```
::Chef::Win32::Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
```